# how the way moment.tz means moment-timezone works in luxon

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

I am trying to convert this sample code moment-timezone into luxon, the code sample in moment is given below,

```
   const momentTask = moment().hour(14).minute(0).second(0).milliseconds(0);

  console.log(
  `This momentTask 1`,
  moment.tz(momentTask, "Europe/Spain")
);
```

Can anyone help me how can i make this into luxon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DateTime.fromObject()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromobject) function to create the luxon DateTime value, setting the zone to 'Europe/Madrid'.

There's no need to set the minute, second, millisecond values, they will default to zero.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const dt = DateTime.fromObject( { hour: 14 }, { zone: 'Europe/Madrid' } );
console.log(dt.toString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ZJuab/UnRq1muTChgrVxJhSgygmL2GMLVmSJN7pcBEqJ1dWPbqN9CiZ6U3HrcApTIJsLnMgXYBYgtVkJ8fWiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you wish to convert to a JS date you can use [`DateTime.toJSDate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetojsdate):

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const dt = luxon.DateTime.now().startOf('day').set({ hour: 14 });

const jsDate = dt.toJSDate();
console.log('Result (to JS Date):', jsDate);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ZJuab/UnRq1muTChgrVxJhSgygmL2GMLVmSJN7pcBEqJ1dWPbqN9CiZ6U3HrcApTIJsLnMgXYBYgtVkJ8fWiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Terry Lennox for your reply, I have a questions if i use const dt = luxon.DateTime.now().startOf('day').set({ hour: 14 }) and do console.log(
  `This dt luxon 1`,
  luxon.DateTime.fromISO(dt.toISO(), { zone: 'utc' }).toJSDate()
); is it correct format to use?

Comment: If you want the result as a JS Date, you could just do dt.toJSDate() directly without needing to convert to ISO and back again.

Comment: But @Terry Lennox how? can you share me the example it would be great help for me.